# HttpRequestException (403 Forbidden) when creating a Google Cloud Storage SignedUrl (GET), only on Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-storage, .net-6.0, google-cloud-run

When running a docker container via Cloud Run, calling `Sign(bucket, objectName, duration, HttpMethod.Get)` on a `Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UrlSigner`, it immediately throws an HttpRequestException, stemming from a 403 Forbidden response.

I suspect that I'm doing something incorrectly, but I have no idea what it is. The Service Account attached to the Cloud Run Revision has a role granting the `storage.objects.get` permission, and is capable of downloading the contents of the storage object.

Here's the code in question:

```
var urlSigner = UrlSigner.FromCredential(GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault());
var signedUrl = urlSigner.Sign("bucketName", "objectName", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30), HttpMethod.Get);
```

If I run the project locally, (with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS pointing to a json service account key), I can create a signed url that works as expected. I can download the contents of the file both executing locally and on cloud run.

The service accounts are the same. I've verified this with the instance metadata at `http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/email`, which matches the "client_email" key in the credential file.

The only difference I've observed is that the `GoogleCredential` returned by `GetApplicationDefault()` wraps a `ServiceAccountCredential` locally, but a `ComputeCredential` when running on the cloud. This seems like a red herring, but I honestly don't know where else to look.

---

Versions that may be relevant:

- Google.Cloud.Storage.V1 4.5.0
- net6.0
- ASP.NET Core 6.0

Some References:

> Never set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an environment variable on a Cloud Run service. Always configure a user-managed service account instead

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/service-identity#per-service-identity

> When you generate a signed URL, you specify a user or service account which must have sufficient permission to make the request that the signed URL will make.

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls

Callstack for Exception:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
  at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.RequestExtensions.PostJsonAsync[TResponse](Object request, HttpClient httpClient, String url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ComputeCredential.SignBlobAsync(Byte[] blob, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UrlSigner.CredentialBlobSigner.CreateSignatureAsync(Byte[] data, BlobSignerParameters _, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.WaitWithUnwrappedExceptions(Task task)
  at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task)
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UrlSigner.CredentialBlobSigner.CreateSignature(Byte[] data, BlobSignerParameters signerParameters)
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UrlSigner.V4Signer.Sign(RequestTemplate requestTemplate, Options options, BlobSignerProvider blobSignerProvider, IClock clock)
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UrlSigner.Sign(RequestTemplate requestTemplate, Options options)
  at Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.UrlSigner.Sign(String bucket, String objectName, TimeSpan duration, HttpMethod httpMethod, Nullable`1 signingVersion)
  at <my code>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service account also needs the `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob` permission when running via Cloud Run.

What the documentation [for using the tools and client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers) doesn't mention is this prerequisite, found on the [signing-urls-manually](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-manually#before-you-begin) page:

> Note: If you're working in a Google Cloud environment such as Cloud Functions or App Engine, the IAM `signBlob` method is used to perform RSA signatures. To call this method, your service account must be assigned the `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob` permission, which is granted in IAM roles such as Service Account Token Creator (`roles/iam.serviceAccountTokenCreator`).

Comment: Note for moderators: sorry for bouncing around accounts here; I created a new one before finding this one. I didn't upvote anything, so I'm crossing my fingers there's no ToS violation or anything?

Comment: Confirm that this works with `var credential = new ComputeCredential()`